# Notifying the User real-time in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm

Currently my code in Plug-in is like this, which throws a business error in the Dynamics CRM.

```
if (value > 1)
     {
       throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("value shouldn't be greater than 1");
     }
```

I want to notify user with a pop-up with a custom message just like this "value shouldn't be greater than 1" without throwing the exception.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
    if (value > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("value shouldn't be greater than 1");
    }
```

For a better understanding of Exceptions and Exception handling visit [The C# language's exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/)

Comment: Can this solution be used in Plug-ins?

Comment: That's another question in which you should consider specifying all dependencies and libraries that involve in the project. `MessageBox.Show` is for the WinForms WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `InvalidPluginExecutionException` is the only option for throwing error/message back to user interface from plugin.

Alternatively you can try moving your plugin logic to a custom action and call that action in JavaScript on save event or another ribbon button click, this way you can handle the message using `Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog`

Comment: Is there is way to not log exception in Plugin Trace logs even with using InvalidPluginExecutionException.

Comment: @NitishReddy: No.